# Why doesn't my function really initialize the array?

Tags: c, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to write a function that initializes an array to zero:

```
void InitializingToZero(int numOfrows, int numOfcols, int array[][20]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfrows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numOfcols; j++) {
            array[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int num_of_rows = 3;    
    int num_of_cols = 3;

    int array[num_of_rows][num_of_cols];

    InitializingToZero(num_of_rows, num_of_cols, array);

    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < num_of_cols; j++) {
            printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

And I get this output:

> 0 0 0
>   0 0 0
>   268501009 0 4200656

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is

```
int num_of_rows = 3;    
int num_of_cols = 3;
```

Then you pass the array with column field `20`. For this reason the array is not initialized properly. That's where the problem lies.

You should do this

```
void InitializingToZero(int numOfrows, int numOfcols, int array[][numOfcols]) {
```

> how can i do it if just know that the max size of the array it's can be 20x20, and the numOfrows, numOfcols are inputs from the user?

Then you do this

```
#define MAXSIZE 20

int array[MAXSIZE ][MAXSIZE];

..


InitializingToZero(num_of_rows, num_of_cols, array);
```

And the funcion would be

```
void InitializingToZero(int numOfrows, int numOfcols, int array[][MAXSIZE]) {
```

Comment: and how can i do it if just know that the max size of the array it's can be 20x20, and the numOfrows, numOfcols are inputs from the user?

Comment: @MasterQuestion.: Good question..i have edited the answer

Comment: @MasterQuestion.: Well sure it would.

Answer (score 0):

I DO know Quentin's response is the right one but why so much complexity for     setting a memory area to 0?

```
int main( void ) {
    const int COLS_AMOUNT = 3;
    static const int ROWS_AMOUNT = 3;

    int num_of_rows = ROWS_AMOUNT;
    int num_of_cols = ROWS_AMOUNT;
    int array[ROWS_AMOUNT][COLS_AMOUNT];

    /* Set to 0 */
    (void)memset( (void*)array, (int)0, sizeof( array ) );

    /* Then check previous set in decreasing order... */
    while( num_of_rows-- ) {
        while( num_of_cols-- ) {
            printf( "array[%d][%d]:%d ",
                    num_of_rows,
                    num_of_cols,
                    array[num_of_rows][num_of_cols] );
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the point of declaring `COLS_AMOUNT` and `ROWS_AMOUNT` instead of just using `num_of_rows` and `num_of_cols` as in the OP's code? What difference does it make? And why is `ROWS_AMOUNT` declared as `static` while `COLS_AMOUNT` is not?

Comment: As for "complexity for setting a memory area to 0"... The value of the question goes beyond zeroing out an `int` array. Next time it could be an array of something else. In general case `memset` approach is OK with integral types, but with floating point types or pointers using `memset` is formally not guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 0):

By declaring your array as

```
int num_of_rows = 3;    
int num_of_cols = 3;

int array[num_of_rows][num_of_cols];
```

you are creating a Variable Length Array (VLA) of size `[3][3]`. But the function parameter is declared as an array `[][20]`.

For proper array parameter passing the first size does not matter (hence the empty `[]`), but the second (and further, if any) sizes must match *exactly*. By creating that mismatch between `[3]` and `[20]` you are effectively lying to your function. The behavior is undefined. The compiler cannot detect and report such mismatches in case of VLAs since their actual sizes are generally not known at compile time.

The problem in your code is easy to fix: just declare the function parameter as a properly sized VLA

```
void InitializingToZero(int numOfrows, int numOfcols, 
                        int array[numOfrows][numOfcols])
```

and leave everything else unchanged. (The first size `[numOfrows]` can be left "empty" as `[]`, but I decided to spell it out for better clarity.)